# Confusing output from Kcachegrind

Tags: kcachegrind

[enter link description here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/eaedf)

Hi,
I am profiling my C code with Kcachegrind. But I am confused with the output tree-map view of the call graph (see the above mentioned link). I have compiled the code: valgrind --tool=callgraph ./Program_name and then kcachegrind callgrind.out.8389. I have the following questions:

1. Above the main() function, u will see a "below main()" and 0x08048bb0 functions. What r these? Is it because the compiler/OS doesn't load the program image and jumps to main() directly. I have read that, before calling main(), a process executes a bulk of code to “clean up the room for execution”. Is this the reason?
2. In the lower part of the tree, u will also see a lot of functions with hexadecimal numbers instead of names. Why is this?
3. Are these hexadecimal numbers absolute addresses (i.e. not offset) or virtual addresses (or Symbol) of the code section of these functions? or not?
4. I have compiled my program in Ubuntu 10.10 using the -g option. Do these hexadecimal numbers have something to do with the absence of "debugging information"?
5. I have tried to use "nm program_name" to figure out whats happening? For the above attached call graph, I have the following output:

> ```
> root@xTR:/home/ahuq/system/client/xTR# nm UDPClientProject 
> 0804af14 d _DYNAMIC
> 0804aff4 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
> 08049b4c R _IO_stdin_used
>          w _Jv_RegisterClasses
> 0804af04 d __CTOR_END__
> 0804af00 d __CTOR_LIST__
> 0804af0c D __DTOR_END__
> 0804af08 d __DTOR_LIST__
> 08049ebc r __FRAME_END__
> 0804af10 d __JCR_END__
> 0804af10 d __JCR_LIST__
> 0804b0a0 A __bss_start
>          U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.1.3
> 0804b098 D __data_start
> 08049b00 t __do_global_ctors_aux
> 08048c30 t __do_global_dtors_aux
> 0804b09c d __dso_handle
> 08048be0 T __gmon_start__
> 08049aba T __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
> 0804af00 d __init_array_end
> 0804af00 d __init_array_start
> 08049a50 T __libc_csu_fini
> 08049a60 T __libc_csu_init
>          U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U __monstartup@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4
> 0804b0a0 A _edata
> 0804b0c4 A _end
> 08049b2c T _fini
> 08049b48 R _fp_hw
> 0804890c T _init
>          U _mcleanup@@GLIBC_2.0
> 08048bb0 T _start
> 080490aa T access_file_insert_data
>          U alarm@@GLIBC_2.0
> 0804922d T append
> 08049ac0 T atexit
>          U bzero@@GLIBC_2.0
> 0804b0a4 b called.3477
>          U calloc@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U ceil@@GLIBC_2.0
> 08049517 T client_timeout_signal_handle
> 0804b0a8 b completed.7065
> 0804b098 W data_start
> 080496e5 T delete_query
> 080494cc T display
> 0804b0ac b dtor_idx.7067
> 0804b0b4 B err
> 08049658 T err_message
> 08049b48 A etext
>          U exit@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U fclose@@GLIBC_2.1
>          U fgets@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U fopen@@GLIBC_2.1
>          U fprintf@@GLIBC_2.0
> 08048c90 t frame_dummy
> 0804953a T get_map_notify_packet
>          U htons@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U inet_pton@@GLIBC_2.0
> 08049733 T insert_query
> 08048cb4 T main
>          U malloc@@GLIBC_2.0
> 080495c6 T map_notify_packet_initialization
> 08048f3c T map_register_packet_initialization
>          U mcount@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U memcpy@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U memset@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U mysql_close@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_errno@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_error@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_init@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_query@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_real_connect@@libmysqlclient_16
>          U mysql_sqlstate@@libmysqlclient_16
> 0804b0c0 B num_of_mapping
>          U perror@@GLIBC_2.0
> 0804b0b0 B position
>          U printf@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U puts@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U recvfrom@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U sendto@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U signal@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U socket@@GLIBC_2.0
> 0804b0a0 B stderr@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U strcat@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U strcpy@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U strlen@@GLIBC_2.0
>          U strtok@@GLIBC_2.0
> 08049781 T tcp_server_access_main
> 0804b0b8 B udp_cli_program_cycle
> 0804b0bc B xx1
> ```

1. I am not seeing the Hexadecimal addresses from the call graph present in the "nm" ouput. I am confused.

Please help me.

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes above main correspond to the code that calls main and returns from it. This is the code that initializes globals and cleans up.

The functions with hexadecimal numbers instead of names correspond to places where debug information or stack information was not available. If you notice, they're typically inside or between libraries. The addresses are absolute, virtual addresses. You won't find them in your program because either they're in dynamically-loaded libraries with no debug information, they were relocated, or they're in parts of your program that weren't compiled with debug symbols (such as code from static libraries). If they were that easy to find, they would have been found for you automatically.

In any event, they only account for about 12% of the consumption, total. They're between the SQL code and the XML code.